# How to I import smart objects into inside my project layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject

I am creating a website preview in photoshop. So far I have completed the header, body and footer. But instead of designing a 'price table' I downloaded a PSD file from online and I would like to integrate this into my own project. I can open the price table .psd file and modify it, but how I do import it into the website preview project I am working on right now?

I changed the price table psd into smart object, but I can't import and unpack it inside my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With photoshop smart object, you can't simply unpack the contents of it to the current document layers.

Think of it as an external file that is linked to your current document.

To edit the smart object, you can double click on the thumbnail in the layer panel, and it will open up the external file in your photoshop, and all the inner guts of the smart object. You can edit the content now. However, if you edit your smart object, all other documents that references this smart object will also see the changes.

If you want to bring all inner layers to your main document, you can select all the layers and drag it out of your smart object document to your main document.

The benefits of smart object is, it is a shared resource that preserves original data of the contents in it.

**Things you can do:**

- Perform non-destructive transforms. Scale, rotate, skew, distort, perspective transform, or warp a layer without losing original image data or quality because the transforms don’t affect the original data.
- Work with vector data.
- Perform non-destructive filtering.
- Edit and automatically update all its linked instances.

**Things you can't do:**

- Actions that will alter pixel data. If you convert the smart object to regular layer without above process, it will be rasterized.

Answer (score 1):

You can just drag and drop the tabel.psd file into the preview project you work on and it will import it as a smart object.

Comment: But I can't edit the prices now. If I do `Edit Contents` it takes me to another new photoshop page

Comment: @samayo it's not a new photoshop file, it's your smart object. As soon as you save it, you will see that your project was updated with your changes.

Comment: @samayo If you want to edit the content in the same phtoshop file, you can just select the content from one PSD file and drag and drop it to the other. It helps if you group the content and you will probably have to rearrange it a bit. Oh and make sure you don't have any locked layers.